# Java Generics: Overriding generic methods, wildcard shorthand?

Tags: java, generics

If I have an interface with a generic method like the following:

```
public interface Thing {
    void <T extends Comparable<? super T>> doSomething(List<T> objects);
}
```

I need that ugly generic typespec in some places, but most implementations don't actually need it:

```
public class ICareAboutSortingThing implements Thing {
    @Override
    public void <T extends Comparable<? super T>> doSomething(List<T> objects) { ... }
}

public class IDontCareAboutSortingThingx100 implements Thing {
    @Override
    public void <T extends Comparable<? super T>> doSomething(List<T> objects) { ... }
}
```

What I would want to write is something like:

```
public class IDontCareAboutSortingThingx100 implements Thing {
    @Override
    public void <?> doSomething(List<?> objects) { ... }
}
```

This should be fully typesafe as far as I understand, but is there any variation of this kind of shorthand that would work?  I do understand that the compiler doesn't allow overriding with non-generic methods, but this is a case of replacing type arguments with wildcards.  My guess is that this isn't actually supported because the compiler could just as easily support

```
public class IDontCareAboutSortingThingx100 implements Thing {
    @Override
    public void <T> doSomething(List<T> objects) { ... }
}
```

i.e. overriding with weaker bounds, but that doesn't seem to be allowed.  Anyhow, just curious if anyone has a magic incantation for cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you're asking for is contravariant method parameters, e.g. a non-generic example looks like:

```
interface I {
    void m(String s);
}

class C implements I {
    @Override
    public void m(Object o) {}
}
```

`void(Object)` is a subsignature of `void(String)` because the widening conversion is always OK. Java doesn't have this.

For generics, you *may* override a generic method to be non-generic:

```
class NotGeneric implements Thing {
    @Override
    public void doSomething(List rawList) {}
}
```

But you basically shouldn't do it. You will get [raw type warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) and you should listen to them. It's available for backwards compatibility.

If it were me, I would just repeat the ugly generic signature because I don't think it's all that ugly.

Something else you could do would be like

```
interface NonGenericThing extends Thing {
    @Override
    default <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
    void doSomething(List<T> list) {
        doSomethingImpl(list);
    }
    void doSomethingImpl(List<?> list);
}
```

And then you implement `NonGenericThing` instead and override `doSomethingImpl`. (Prior to Java 8, `NonGenericThing` must be an abstract class.)

Of course that might not be feasible if `Thing` is actually a large interface. You could also declare `Thing` this way to begin with, if it's appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, similar to the conclusion and solution I came to as well.  I'm bound to Java 7 unfortunately, but I ended up swapping the interface for a class that exposed both override points, with one delegating to the other by default.I could have sworn Java supported widening argument types on override, but I guess I haven't actually tried it recently :P.  Bit of a shame really; for the non-generic case, I can understand this as being an optimization for method signature lookup/binding, but type erasure (kind of) makes that irrelevant.  Guess it's consistent though :/.

Comment: +1 on no raw types though; I can understand the use in private-scope code in very controlled circumstances if the usage is known to be safe, but sometimes they appear in public interfaces too, and it makes me (and my IDE) cry.  Even worse though is `public <T> ThingProducingTs<T> getThing(String)`, which makes my eyes glass over with rage.

Comment: Well generic types need to be declared somehow. Java is more terse than some other languages (*cough* C++).

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure where you're trying to get to but couldn't you encapsulate the restrictions in a separate class?

```
public class It<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    public List<T> them;
}

public interface Thing {

    void doSomething(It<String> them);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers my question, but does answer a related question: how to get a wildcard comparable-to-self type (namely `It<?>`).  I did make use of this trick in that manner too, it's pretty useful despite the file bloat of extra empty interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

**You can embed the type information into a class**:

```
public class IDontCareAboutSortingThingx100<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Thing<T> {

    @Override
    public void doSomething(List<T> objects) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry; there is actually a need for the method itself to be generic here, since the same instance will be used for multiple different parameters for `T`.  (There are also other methods on the interface, which I omitted to shorten things up.)